# the correction of $(this) == $('.element')

Tags: jquery

for example , I have some element

```
<div class="elem1"></div>
<div class="elem2"></div>
```

and 1 jquery function

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myFunction = function() { 

         if ( $(this) == $('.elem1') ) { /* Condition 1 run */ }
         else if ( $(this) == $('.elem2') ) { /* Condition 2 run */ }

    }
})( jQuery );


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.elem1').myFunction() ;
});
```

I need if I set this function on .elem1 , Condition 1 run , else Condition 2 run .

but `$(this) == $('.elem1')` or `$(this) == $('.elem2')` are not logical ,

so what would u guy suggest me to do ( for correction of `$(this) == $('element')` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check this

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myFunction = function () {

        if ($(this).is('.elem1')) { /* Condition 1 run */
        } else if ($(this).is('.elem2')) { /* Condition 2 run */
        }

    }
})(jQuery);
```

`$(selector)` will return a new jQuery object every time it is called, so checking object equality will not match

Note: As noted by @Bhushan in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819105/the-correction-of-this-element/32819130#answer-32819139), if you are just checking whether a class is present, then using [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) is better

Comment: tnx my friend , but this not work for $(window) element , Please check the help

Comment: @DaninNa sorry what do you mean by not matching for window element

Comment: $(window).myFunction() and 'if ( $(this).is(window) )' not work , but $('body').myFunction() and if ( $(this).is('body') ) run

Comment: @DaninNa what should happen in that case... the window element does not have any class associated with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90777/discussion-between-danin-na-and-arun-p-johny).

Comment: tnx my bro for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you can use `.hasClass()`

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myFunction = function() { 

         if ( $(this).hasClass('elem1') ) { /* Condition 1 run */ }
         else if ( $(this).hasClass('elem2') ) { /* Condition 2 run */ }

    }
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass the parameter to the function

(function( $ ){

```
$.fn.myFunction = function(var x) { 

     if (x=='elem1')  { /* Condition 1 run */ }
     else if ( x=='elem2')  { /* Condition 2 run */ }

}})(jQuery );
```

Comment: You can check their ids, or their classes, but you have to know that more than one element could have the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can check their IDs o their classes, but you must know that more than one element could have the same class.

```
if ( $(this).attr('id') == $(".elem1").attr('id') ) { /**/ }
if ( $(this).attr('class') == $(".elem1").attr('class') ) { /**/ }
```